# Android Studio rendering problems with version 1.2.1.1

Tags: xml, android-studio, ide, render

I am using the latest version of Android Studio 1.2.1.1. I am facing the rendering issue when I try to view the XML design, Can anyone tell me what should I do ? Here is a screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your Android **API level** in the preview, it is currently in `22`, set it as `21`. It will work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked out.Will be glad if you can help me out [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235139/android-studio-1-2-1-1-emulator-error)

Comment: Any idea what caused that exception?